# I face this error while running the first app in flutter , how to solve it?

Tags: android, flutter

This is my log message, Android studio 3.1.2 , I get the same error in intellij and also in visual studio code :

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Finished with error: Exit code 1 from: X:\Android(exp+1)\flutter\flutter_appnew\android\gradlew.bat -v:
'X:\Android' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

This is my flutter doctor result :

```
C:\Users\kunda>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.3.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.431], locale en-IN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.1)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.22.2)
[√] Connected devices (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move your flutter project to a directory without parenthesis, so e.g. `X:\Android\flutter\flutter_appnew`

Comment: it is outside parentehesis , in the lof the parenthesis is there to describe path